# i want to be able to set workbook from a cell value, it doesn't seem to work for some reason

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code:

```
Sub export_toFEP2()
 Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
 Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim x As String, lastrow As String
Dim lRow As Long, kRow As Long, i As Long
Dim u As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

ThisWorkbook.Activate

Sheets("FEP Selection").Activate
u = Sheets("FEP Selection").Range("File_Name").Value2
Set wb = Workbooks(u)
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Ship Arrivals")
Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("FEP copy")

lastrow = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow

If ws2.Range("D" & i).Value = "TRUE" Then

lRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws2.Range("A" & i).Value2, ws.Range("A2:CS2"), 0)
kRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CLng(ws2.Range("B" & i).Value), ws.Range("A1:A145"), 0)

If lRow > 0 And kRow > 0 Then
MsgBox lRow
MsgBox kRow
ws.Cells(kRow, lRow).Value = ws2.Range("C" & i).Value
End If
End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

The problem i am having is that it does not do anything but does not give any errors either.
the variable should pick up a value like "A.xls" (that's the value of file name range), it changes every time, hence, i have a range with the file name.
if i change to the

```
Set wb = Workbooks(u)
```

to

```
Set wb = Workbooks("A1.xls")
```

it seems to work, but that defeats the purpose as the file name is variable.

thank you for your help :)

Comment: If the workbook in question is open, omit the `.xls` when you set the value of `wb`. Something like `Set wb = Workbooks(Replace(u, ".xls", ""))`

Comment: that just gives me a subscript out of range error.

Comment: I just came across something really weird, if i get rid off the 
'If ws2.Range("D" & i).Value = "TRUE" Then' and the first 'End if', it seems to work.

Comment: Oh good lord, i have figured it out, it should have been If ws2.Range("D" & i).Value = "True" (not TRUE) Then.
sorry for the dumb question. Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: :) I submitted it as an answer as well. If you mark it as the accepted solution (checkmark on the left), this question won't pop up for people who are trying to answer questions with no solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the workbook in question is open, omit the `.xls` when you set the value of `wb`.

Something like:
`Set wb = Workbooks(Replace(u, ".xls", ""))`